# Python code to parse JSON data from CuckooML, involving many file operations

Tags: python, json, file, machine-learning

I have written a code that will parse JSON file from a cuckoo report.
The issue is am not a good coder. I have got the program to give me the desired output.

The real challenge that I am facing is I have written multiple file open and close. How can I reduce it to a minimum? Because the JSON file are huge and the parsing time is approx. 10 sec.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
from pprint import pprint
import pprint
import os, json
import pandas as pd
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('*.json'):
   print filename
   with open(filename) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
to_dict = data
for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_created']:
    pid1 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_created']   

for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['regkey_written']:
    pid2 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['regkey_written']

for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['dll_loaded']:
    pid3 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['dll_loaded']

for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_opened']:
    pid4 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_opened']

for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['regkey_opened']:
    pid5 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['regkey_opened']

for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_written']:
    pid6 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_written']
#
for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_exists']:
    pid7 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_exists']

for item in to_dict['behavior']['processes']:
    pid8 = to_dict['behavior']['processes']

write_in_file = open('resultFile.txt','w')
pprint.pprint(pid1,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid2,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid3,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid4,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid5,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid6,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid7,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid8,write_in_file)
#pprint.pprint(pid9,write_in_file)
#pprint.pprint(pid10,write_in_file)
write_in_file.close()   

################################################### Code to Reduce the Noise ##########################################
with open('resultFile.txt', 'r') as file :
    filedata = file.read()
## Replace the target string
    filedata = filedata.replace('[', ' ')
    filedata = filedata.replace('{',' ')
    filedata = filedata.replace('}', ' ')
    filedata = filedata.replace('\\\\', ' ')
    filedata = filedata.replace('[', ' ')
    filedata = filedata.replace(']', ' ')
    filedata = filedata.replace(',', ' ')
write_in_file.close()
with open('resultFile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
write_in_file.close()
################################################### Code to count the Frequency ###################################### 
with open('resultFile.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
text=filedata.split()
mydict={}
for word in text:
    if word not in mydict.keys():
        mydict[word]=1
    else:
        count=mydict[word]
        mydict[word]=count+1
write_in_file = open('resultFile.txt','w')
pprint.pprint (mydict,write_in_file)  #<-------In case you want to see which line is being counted how many times -just uncomment this line.# This is for debugging purpose
#pprint.pprint (mydict.values(),write_in_file) #<-------This is what we want.
write_in_file.close()
################################################### Code to Take care of the Numbering System ######################################

infile=open('resultFile.txt', 'r')
lines=infile.readlines()
infile.close()
outtext = ['%d %s' % (i, line) for i, line in enumerate(lines)]
outfile = open("resultFile.txt","w")
outfile.writelines(str("".join(outtext)))
outfile.close()
#
with open('resultFile.txt', 'r') as file :
    filedata = file.read()
    filedata = filedata.replace(',', ' ')
    filedata = filedata.replace('[', ' ')
    filedata = filedata.replace(']', ' ')
write_in_file.close()
#filedata = filedata.replace('', '')
with open('resultFile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
write_in_file.close()
```

So is there any other way I could reduce any operations?

My final output that I want to look like is as follows:

```
0    1
1    12
2    3
3    98
4    2
.    .
.    .
.    .
```

where the serial numbers are the unique numbers of entities and the corresponding number is the frequency (the number of times that entity appears)

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/31562) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Are you sure about that initial `for` loop? It looks like you're taking only the last file to fill `to_dict`.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I will be more careful next time.Thank you :)

Comment: @ChatterOne Yes. I mean it is giving me the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

```
import pandas as pd
```

is never used. So it may be deleted.

---

```
    data = json.load(json_file)
to_dict = data
```

The data variable is used only in the subsequent statement `to_dict = data`. Why not use directly

```
    to_dict = json.load(json_file)
```

---

```
for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_created']:
    pid1 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_created']
```

(and subsequent): Do you really assign only the last item to `pid1` (as you repeatedly  rewrite `pid1` in the `for` loop)?

---

This is horrible:

```
for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_created']:
    pid1 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_created']   

for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['regkey_written']:
    pid2 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['regkey_written']

for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['dll_loaded']:
    pid3 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['dll_loaded']

for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_opened']:
    pid4 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_opened']

for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['regkey_opened']:
    pid5 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['regkey_opened']

for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_written']:
    pid6 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_written']
#
for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_exists']:
    pid7 = to_dict['behavior']['summary']['file_exists']

for item in to_dict['behavior']['processes']:
    pid8 = to_dict['behavior']['processes']
```

DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Refactor it. Use e. g. a dictionary instead of `8` variables `pid1`, ..., `pid8`. Use `for` loop instead of `8` times the same thing. As a minimal change you may write it as

```
pids = {}
actions = ['file_created', 'regkey_written', 'dll_loaded', (and so on)]

for action in actions:
    for item in to_dict['behavior']['summary'][action]:
        pids[action] = to_dict['behavior']['summary'][action]
```

Consequently, you may use `pids` directory for looping - instead of your current

```
write_in_file = open('resultFile.txt','w')
pprint.pprint(pid1,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid2,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid3,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid4,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid5,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid6,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid7,write_in_file)
pprint.pprint(pid8,write_in_file)
#pprint.pprint(pid9,write_in_file)
#pprint.pprint(pid10,write_in_file)
write_in_file.close()
```

you may then write

```
with open('resultFile.txt','w') as write_in_file:
    for action in actions:
        pprint.pprint(pids[action], write_in_file)
```

---

```
filedata = filedata.replace(',', ' ')
filedata = filedata.replace('[', ' ')
filedata = filedata.replace(']', ' ')
```

may become

```
filedata = filedata.replace(',', ' ').replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ')
```

(as chaining string methods is recommended) or

```
for c in ',[]':
    filedata = filedata.replace(c, ' ')
```

---